# PayPal Buy-Now button, how to Add my own price?

Tags: php, paypal

I have a form that a user fills out prior to reaching the PayPal Buy Now button. The form contains information such as the users name and the amount they will be paying (in a hidden field).

I know there probably is a way to pass the name variable to PayPal using the Advanced Variables feature, but is there a way to alter the buttons price?

And can I do this using PHP variables?

Eg: `item_name=<?php $myitem ?>`

Any advice would be great!

EDIT: Form as requested

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XXXX">
<input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal — The safer, easier way to pay online.">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: Please post the according html from your button.

Comment: please paste your sample paypal form. What do you mean _alter the buttons price_

Comment: @antoniom I mean that when I create the Buy Now button on the PayPal site it asks for a dollar amount (presumably what the user will be asked to pay upon clicking the button). I want to know how to change that initial amount by using a php var from my form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your question, you have to put the `amount` hidden field on paypal form.
e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="100">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
```

This form will prompt paypal to ask $100 from buyer.

of course you can add your own var there e.g.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="<?php echo $amount;?>">
```

HTH

Comment: Ah ok - would you need to set any of those variables up in your PayPal account?

Comment: No there is no need! See https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables for a complete reference of the variables that you can use

Comment: That won't work with a 'hosted button' (which is what OP has).

Comment: @antoniom I was thinking on the same thing put a input type hidden, but what if a person change the value of the input ? I mean with right click of the mouse you can see the source code and edit that value..I'm right ? There is not another suggestion? or you guys think with that is enough?

Comment: @PaulNoris when PayPal returns its transaction data via IPN or PDT you can always crosscheck the amount that the user paid vs the amount that you requested to pay. If these numbers are different you can act accordingly.

Comment: Nice answer @antoniom I gonna look that, thank you !! If you have some example would be helpful for me !!

Answer (score 0):

I cannot even get this working with an unhosted button.  It seems Paypal never lets you change the amount.  I see it like this :

hosted button : amount is set in the code pointed to by the 'hosted button id'
unhosted button : PayPal encrypts the information, of which amount is part of

so, in either case you cannot change it, or at least, I haven't been able to do this.

Having said that, there is a variable called 'amount' you can use.  So, I'm very confused about this.

Comment: Did you check out the variables documentation? https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables