# PayPal: Simple button getting 'contains an incorrectly formatted item amount'

Tags: forms, api, paypal

I know there are many questions like this already on SO but none of their answers are working for me.

I am using the simple button form:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input name="cmd" type="hidden" value="_s-xclick" />
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value="500.00">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="AUD">
<input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="XXXXX" />
<input alt="PayPal &mdash; The safer, easier way to pay online." name="submit" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/btn/btn_paynowCC_LG.gif" type="image" />
<img src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_AU/i/scr/pixel.gif" border="0" alt="" width="1" height="1" />
</form>
```

But get the error: 
`The link you have used to enter the PayPal system contains an incorrectly formatted item amount.`

From what I've researched it is because the value needs 2 decimal places and no currency symbol. But as you can see I've tried that. Other versions I have tried are:

```
 value=500.00>
 value="$500.00">
 value="500">
 value="500.00">
 value='500.00'>
```

Would anyone know what's going on? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I think I have solved it.

The issue seems to be I was using a hosted Buy Now button rather then normal buy now button. The only difference I can tell is the line

```
<input name="hosted_button_id" type="hidden" value="XXXXX" />
```

After much struggling and 2 useless calls to PayPal I found the button I was meant to use here:

https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_html_buynow_buttons#id089UG070BRO

Let me say for the record that the PayPal API documentation is a complete nightmare!

Comment: That's what I warned you for in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153585/paypal-buy-now-button-add-my-own-price already. The reason is that you can't have a 'hosted button' (details residing on PayPal's side) *and* override the amount at the same time. It would defeat the entire purpose of using a 'hosted button': so that malicious users can't override the amount by simply changing it inside the <form>.